# One question about semi-algebraic variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, real-algebraic-geometry

We identify $\mathbb{C}^n$ with $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$, and let $C\subset \mathbb{C}^n$ be a semi-algebraic curve, then can we always find a complex algebraic curve $V'\subset \mathbb{C}^n$ containing $C$?

In general, let $V\subset \mathbb{C}^n$ be a semi-algebraic set of dimension $m$, then is it true that the dimension of the Zariski closure of $V$ always has complex dimension $m$?

Thanks very much!

Comment: Note that for the second question, the answer is clearly no - take any complex variety of complex dimension $n$, regard it as a real variety of real dimension $2n$, and then take it's complex Zariski closure. You get back exactly what you started with, but $n\neq 2n$ unless $n=0$. It probably makes more sense to ask for the Zariski closure to have complex dimension bounded above by $m$.